# VBAでCOMコンポーネント使って特定のサービスを取得する方法を、C#(.Net)で行う方法について

Tags: c#, .net, vba

こんにちは。
現在、VBAを使用して、特定アプリ内の情報をCOMコンポーネント使い、その特定サービスを取得しました。
それを同じようにC#(.Net)でもできるのかお聞きしたいです。.Netは、VisualStudio2019を使用したものです。
VBAの例を以下です。

```
'オブジェクトのインスタンス化
Set xxxApp = GetObject(, "XXXXApplication") '(XXXXApplication:COMコンポーネントのアプリケーション名）

'「コンポーネント」のサービスを取得する。
Set UiSvc = xxxApp.GetService("YYYY_Service") '(YYYY_Service:COMコンポーネントのサービス名）
```

C#では、まずCOMコンポーネントの取得をすることはできました。

```
var setObj = Interaction.GetObject(null, "XXXXApplication");
```

しかし、VBAと同じようにサービス名"YYYY_Service"を取得するところがよく分かっておりません。
何か良い方法があれば教えていただけますでしょうか。

お願いいたします。

Comment: その特定のCOMコンポーネント固有の機能なのか、それとも汎用のAPIを使っていてサービス名称だけが固有なのか、そうした情報はありませんか？ 使っているCOMコンポーネントの実名/ベンダーや版数、そして取得しようとしているサービスの実名等が明記出来るなら追記したほうが助言や回答が出やすいと思われます。 それからC#で続けてそのまま`setObj.GetService()`を記述したり実行した場合にどうなるのか(ビルド出来ないとか出来るけれど実行時にエラーになるとか)とその際のエラーメッセージ等があれば略さずに全てを提示してみてください。

Comment: `XXXXApplication`コンポーネント特有の機能なため、この部分を伏せられている限り議論できないと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。具体的に言うべきことは具体的に言いたいと思います。COMコンポーネントはEcadを使用しておりました。少なくとも、GetServiceはEcad特有のCOMコンポーネントを使用していたはずです。radianさんのアドバイスで解決したので一度終えたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamic型の変数に入れれば、おそらくVBAと同じように扱えると思います。

```cs
dynamic ecadApp = Interaction.GetObject(null, "XXXXApplication");
dynamic uiSvc = ecadApp.GetService("YYYY_Service");
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。dynamicを使用して上手くGetServiceの内容を取得できました。